# Timezone with 12h time format (AM/PM)

Tags: debian, time, timezone

I have a problem with timezone in debian

I need to set up zone with 12h format (AM/PM) throughout the system. Locale set to "en_US.UTF.8", output "date" command is correctly. Time format in "timedatectl" is incorrect (24h). Any ideas?

Locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

timedatectl

```
    Local time: Mon 2022-02-21 20:09:15 CET
           Universal time: Mon 2022-02-21 19:09:15 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2022-02-21 19:09:14
                Time zone: Europe/Warsaw (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

date

```
Mon 21 Feb 2022 08:09:08 PM CET
```

systemctl process status

```
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-21 20:09:01 CET; 22s ago
```

Answer (score 1):

12 hour AM/PM or 24 hour format is a matter of locale preference - not the time zone.

Comment: Ok, how can i get 12H (AM/PM) in systemctl process status? In my process i have a errors with bad parsing time. I think changing the time display to AM / PM will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

timedatectl will not print 12-hour time, calls strftime() with [`%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v250/src/timedate/timedatectl.c#L105)

GNU [coreutils date](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v9.0/src/date.c#L594) calls localized functions which in some cases can call strftime() with hour minute second of [`%I:%M:%S`](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/3a24ff8a1045d8d38824088c0984bb59d0192e65/lib/nstrftime.c#L1167-L1172)  %I is 12-hour hours.  Also date can be called with a custom format, for example `date +%r`